# Disabling notifications for Samsung Messages

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-messages

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S5. I switched to using Google Hangouts for SMS. I cannot disable the default Samsung Messages' notification, so I get a duplicate of each notification from the messages.

I unchecked "Show notifications" under Application Manager and it doesn't seem to work.

How can I disable it?

Comment: do you have same SMS Account? I mean if you have multiple google accounts ONLY one can be configured to use with Google Hangout and other Accounts will continue to use default SMS app and hence you might be getting those Notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change this option in your default SMS app? It's under settings on the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the default SMS app.

But be careful, you may face problems receiving and sending messages after that if you have a KitKat or Lollipop due to Google Android restrictions.

Comment: I've actually tried this. It doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What's the OS you are using?